# Treat macro arguments in Common Lisp as (case-sensitive) strings

Tags: string, common-lisp, symbols, case-sensitive

(This is one of those things that seems like it should be so simple that I imagine there may be a better approach altogether)

I'm trying to define a macro (for CLISP) that accepts a variable number of arguments as symbols (which are then converted to case-sensitive strings).

```
(defmacro symbols-to-words (&body body)
  `(join-words (mapcar #'symbol-name '(,@body))))
```

converts the symbols to uppercase strings, whereas

```
(defmacro symbols-to-words (&body body)
  `(join-words (mapcar #'symbol-name '(|,@body|))))
```

treats ,@body as a single symbol, with no expansion.

Any ideas? I'm thinking there's probably a much easier way altogether.

Answer (score 6):

The symbol names are uppercased during the reader step, which occurs before macroexpansion, and so there is nothing you can do with macros to affect that. You can globally set [READTABLE-CASE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rdtabl.htm), but that will affect all code, in particular you will have to write all standard symbols in uppercase in your source. There is also a '-modern' option for CLISP, which provides lowercased version for names of the standard library and sets the reader to be case-preserving, but it is itself non-standard. I have never used it myself so I am not sure what caveats actually apply.

The other way to control the reader is through reader macros. Common Lisp already has a reader macro implementing a syntax for case-sensitive strings: the [double quote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_de.htm). It is hard to offer more advice without knowing why you are not just using it.

Answer (score 3):

As Ramarren correctly says, the case of symbols is determined during read time. Not at macro expansion time.

Common Lisp has a syntax for specifying symbols without changing the case:

`|This is a symbol|` - using the vertical bar as multiple escape character.

and there is also a backslash - a single escape character:

```
CL-USER > 'foo\bar
|FOObAR|
```

Other options are:

- using a different global readtable case
- using a read macro which reads and preserves case
- using a read macro which uses its own reader

Also note that a syntax for something like `|,@body|` (where body is spliced in) does not exist in Common Lisp. The splicing in does only work for lists - not symbol names. `|`, the vertical bar, surrounds character elements of a symbol. The explanation in the Common Lisp Hyperspec is a bit cryptic: [Multiple Escape Characters](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/02_ade.htm).